# Design for persistent objects with decoupled storage

Tags: oop, object, design-patterns

An application uses several type of data coded as objects. These objects require to be persistent, and the storage back-end may change (file system, sqlite, nedb are likely options).

What are the best way to design the related code to minimize the hassle to change storage ? A specific Store object to which I would pass my objects ? Have my objects inherit from on that does the storage ? Should my object "self-store" or not ?

For information, the practical case is for a local webapp using node-webkit (javascript) but the answer should probably not be language dependent, as long as it is object oriented.

Comment: imo, The objects should not `self-store` as that is an extra layer of coupling that all objects would need - even temporary ones. imo, The repository pattern is useful for this. It decouples the object from the actual store. If defined using interfaces it can be quite flexible especially when testing etc.

Comment: look @ data mappers

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a functionality that may change, abstract it by introducing an interface, and provide an implementation. In your specific example, you can define an interface `IRepository`, which would have create/read/update/delete methods for manipulating your objects. Then, you can provide implementations that work with specific storage. In your unit tests, for example, you may use a memory-based implementation that does not even deal with files/DBs/etc, but keeps data in lists.